# Tuning for Naive Bayes

Tags: naive-bayes

If you are tuning a Naive Bayes model using `caret`, can someone explain how increasing or decreasing the Laplace smoother and bandwidth impact the results?
I understand that the Laplace smoother is to account for the zero-frequency issue, but I have been unable to find a suitable definition for bandwidth.

For example, if I have this grid

```
grid <- expand.grid(
  usekernel = c(TRUE, FALSE),
  fL = seq(0,5,0.5), # Bandwidth
  adjust = seq(0,5,0.5) # Laplace
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [caret](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/caret.pdf)'s doc, it seems like the definitions `fL` and `adjust` are interchanged (compared to your comments in the code). So, `adjust` is the bandwidth. It is an input for [KDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation), which is a non-parametric density estimation method. It is only used when `usekernel` option is `TRUE`. Otherwise, you don't need the parameter, since the density estimation method is Gaussian. The bandwidth in KDE represents the amount of spread in KDE *kernel* function.